# Command-line Options: Should short options be restricted to 1 character?

Tags: python, argparse

I'm trying to get my head around command-line arguments for Python and have been reading the Standard Library documentation about the [argparse module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html).  They mention the concept of short and long form command-line options, with short form options specified with a single dash, `-` (eg `-f`), and long form options specified with two dashes, `--` (eg `--filename`).

Nowhere does it describe the difference between the short form and long form options, except that one is obviously shorter than the other.  After Googling the concepts it seems to me short form options originated long ago in C.  Back then they were a single character.

My question is, should I continue to use only a single character for short form command-line options in Python?  Is that what users will expect?  Or is it acceptable to use two of three character abbreviations in the short options (eg `-fn`)?

Comment: It is what I would expect. Because short options are only a single character you can chain multiple using only 1 dash. So `du -hx` has the same results as `du -h -x` which means human readable (`-h`) and single filesystem (`-x`)

Comment: Many programs have long "short" options, like in your `-fn` example. However, they have to use another argument parser as the normal expects the short options to be one character so `-fn` is the two options `-f -n`.

Comment: Thanks Wolph and Joachim.  Your explanations make it perfectly clear why I should restrict short options to only a single character.

Comment: These days a `-fn` option would only be acceptable in legacy programs for backward compatibility, such as gcc's `-static` and such. Modern programs follow the convention described in other answers, and so do `argparse` and its predecessor `optparse`.

Answer (score 2):

I believe we could make a reference for `POSIX` standard and `GNU` coding guidelines. Despite there isn't a sort of 'global' standard, I suppose we should stick to these rules at least while we code for *nix.

According to the [POSIX conventions](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html) each option name should be a single alphanumeric character (the alnum character classification) from the portable character set. And all options should be preceded by the '-' delimiter character.

[GNU guideline](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Argument-Syntax.html) adds *long options*

> Long options consist of -- followed by a name made of alphanumeric characters and dashes. Option names are typically one to three words long, with hyphens to separate words. Users can abbreviate the option names as long as the abbreviations are unique.